# Object3D in Objece3D does not work

Tags: three.js

I created some Scene,added to group_lev2;
group_lev2 added to another group.  Like this:

var group_top=new THREE.Object3D();
var group_lev2=new THREE.Object3D();
var scene1,scene2,scene3...
group_lev2.add(scene1);
group_lev2.add(scene2);
group_lev2.add(scene3);
group_top.add(group_lev2);

I run it in firefox,
But I see nothing in my page.
I putted these scenes into root group, displayed;
But I want lots of groupe,to use different animate.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want, but you need new THREE.Scene() instead of new THREE.Object3D(), right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r76/three.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict"
var scenetop, scenelev2, scene1, scene2, scene3;
var camera, light, mesh, geometry, material, renderer;

window.onload = function() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(750, 750);
  renderer.setClearColor(0xcccccc, 1);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 750/750);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 8);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  light.position.set(10, 10, 10);
// scenetop
  scenetop = new THREE.Scene();
  scenetop.add(light);
// scenelev2
  scenelev2 = new THREE.Scene();
  scenetop.add(scenelev2);
// scene1
  scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
  addsphere(.5, -1, -1, 0xffcccc, scene1);
  scenelev2.add(scene1);
// scene2
  scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
  addsphere(.5, -1, +1, 0xccffcc, scene2);
  scenelev2.add(scene2);
// scene3
  scene3 = new THREE.Scene();
  addsphere(.5, +1, -1, 0xccccff, scene3);
  scenelev2.add(scene3);

  renderer.render(scenetop, camera);
}
function addsphere (pr, px, py, pcolor, pscene) {
  geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(pr);
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:pcolor } );
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.translateX(px);
  mesh.translateY(py);
  pscene.add(mesh);
}
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your demo,it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add scene1, scene2 ... as a child to group_lev2

```
    group_lev2.children(X) = sceneX;
```